# Draw images inside a image frame : Android

Tags: android, imageview

I want to load image inside a photo frame. 
Here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/l59ogltcgwaycta/frame.jpg?dl=0) is an example frame, Where I want to load image inside the white box. I also want to move it or zoom in/out by touch for bring it in perfect posotion, after load.

Could anyone tell me please, which approach would be best to implement this things or any good example that may helpful for me?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems just a green rectangle. It could be the background of a RelativeLayout. The two white areas could be two ImageViews. Just load the pictures inside them, et voilà.

Comment: thanks. So your suggestion is, add that image as a background and then add two ImageView on it..  but what happen, if white area is a circle, oval or heart shape.?? It is work then?

Comment: If the images are shaped accordingly (with a transparent background, yes). OR you are possibly asking for a  couple of **masks** (rectangles with a transparent **hole**, which can be any shape): the images will be partially covered, and only what's under the hole will be visible

Comment: Thanks. Yes, for my case white area with heart shape or rectangle is transparent.So, can I directly apply ImageView on that background. I am confused that will it appear on the top op the shape or behind of the shape.

Comment: 2 possible ways: use an ImageView on top (the one with the heart-shaped hole) and have the other ImageView **under** it OR just overlay two images in one (the third is the combination of the two - probably the easisest way) OR cut the heart shape out of a single ImageView.